# Ubuntu Process high memory usage (almost 99%)

Tags: ram, process, memory-usage

I'm googling this process name and I found nothing, any idea?
using Ubuntu 16.04
this is getting 100% memory usage and my computer freezes many times, I have an intel core i5 6th generation, 8GB ram, 1Terabyte HD, and using just 20% of the space it's not would be happening
[image: high memory usage]

Comment: I see only 0% CPU.

Comment: but it's memory usage not cpu, I needed to way some seconds before hitting print screen button because the system was freezed

Comment: What is the process name?

Comment: I do not see any high mem usage processes either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a user on the archlinux forum with a similar query/problem there are several possible solutions suggested there that you might try. here is the link https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=189975